# Vim: Most efficient way to copy newline separated list in the middle of text to a comma separated list

Tags: vim

I have this text:

```
* configobj
* pymongo
* tornado
* pandas
```

and would like to transform it to:

```
configobj, pymongo, tornado, pandas
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

---

**Addition**: this is what I came up with on my own:

1. Starting on the `c` in `configobj` do `C-v e j j j y` to yank the block of text.
2. Then `p` to place it where I want it.
3. Then go to the end of the `configobj` line
4. Hit `C-v` and `j j j` to the bottom
5. `A` then insert a `,` and hit `C-[`
6. Use `C-v` again with `x` to delete the final spaces and remove the final comma.

And then, realize that the last letter of `configobj` got cut off, so I have to go back and add that.

**Edit**:

I apologize for not specifying that this is only *part* of the buffer, and not the *whole* buffer.

Comment: are those `*` in text?

Comment: What have you gotten so far (even if it's ineffective)?!

Comment: @Kent Yes, the `*`s are in the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Visually select your block.
2. Replace every newline followed by a `*` with a `,`:

   ```
   :'<,'>s/\n\*/,
   ```
3. Delete the first `*<space>`.

   ```
   xx
   ```

Answer (score 2):

if just for the example in your question, you could do it in one-shot:

```
%s/^\*//|%join|s/ /, /g
```

The above cmd will not work if the line has spaces.

You could also consider to install `Join` plugin (https://github.com/sk1418/Join) and press:

```
%s/^\*//|%J ', '
```

This will work for the case if line has space too.

Answer (score 2):

This is a decent use case for a macro.

With your cursor on the first star run the following (`^[` is <kbd>Escape</kbd>):

```
qqxxA,^[Jq3@qx
```

The breakdown:

- `qq` - Begin recording a macro into the register `q`
- `xx` - Delete `*` and the space
- `A,^[` - Append a `,` to the end of the line and exit insert mode
- `J` - Join the next line with the current line
- `q` - End the macro
- `3@q` - Run the macro three times
- `x` - Remove the trailing comma

An afterthought:  If your list elements end with punctuation marks (`.`, `?`, `!`) then the behavior of <kbd>J</kbd> is affected by the `joinspaces` option so this macro may leave extra spaces in between the elements in those cases.  See `:help 'joinspaces'` for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I would use regular expressions:

```
%s/^\s*\*\s*//    -- remove stars
%s/$\n/, /        -- join
%s/, $//          -- remove the last trailing comma
```

Comment: Is there a way for the regular expression to work on only the list and not the entire buffer?

Comment: Ye, the simplest is to visually mark (using `V`) the lines you want to transform and then press `:`. You will get `:'<,'>` which means "apply the following command just to highlighted lines". Then you add the rest of the expression, e.g. `:'<,'>s/foo/bar/g`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the most efficient way to do it but it gets the job done:

```
:execute "normal ggVGJ" | s/\v\s*\*\s*// | s/\s*\*\s*/, /g
```

It yields:

```
configobj, pymongo, tornado, pandas
```